# Plot recursive signal in Matlab

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab, signal-processing

I need to create and plot this signal in matlab with 2000 points:

```
 x(n) = 0.6530 x(n-1) - 0.7001 x(n-2) + v(n)
```

Where $x(-1)=x(-2)=0$ and $v(n) =$ white noise

I have no clue about how to do it since I'm pretty new to matlab, I would appreciate any hint to begin with, but I would apreciate more some code.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't know any fast way to do this in matlab. For loops are excrutiatingly slow so you should never foor loop stuff in Matlab. This is a special case of an IIR filter. There should be addons to Matlab or maybe open source mex-functions which do this.

Answer (score 1):

A simple code is

```
  x = zeros(1,2000); % Initialize x-vector
  v = rand(1,2000); % Create noise v
  for n = 3:2000 % Main loop
      x(n) = 0.6530*x(n-1) - 0.7001*x(n-2)+ v(n);
  end
  plot(x)
```

Although, you have to adjust exactly what you mean by white noise. I just added some uniform noise between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: `wgn` generates white Gaussian noise

Comment: @oldrinb Thanks. So maybe something like `v = wgn(1,2000,0)` would work for OP's use.

Answer (score 0):

You want to start off by initializing an array of all of your inputs

```
n=3:2000
```

You also know that you will have an array of all your answers, so let's initialize an array for that

```
x=zeros(2000)
```

now let's go through every element of n and fill in the appropriate x value

```
for i=n
   x(i)=.6530*x(i-1)-.7001*x(i-2)+v(i)
end
```

now we can plot everything

```
plot(1:2000,x)
```

I am not exactly sure what the white noise is supposed to be, but you will have to fill in your own values for that

Comment: If you can avoid it you should never use for loops like this in Matlab. It is extremely slow. Although I don't know of any built in function which does this in Matlab.

Comment: @mathreadler Yes, for-loops are slow in Matlab, but you exaggerating a lot.  I wrote a script in Matlab that looped 2000 times and it took less than $1/10000$ of a second to finish. Although, you can't completely trust timings when they are at those low times.

Comment: @mathguy The command `x=zeros(2000)` initializes a $2000\times 2000$ matrix, not just a vector of length $2000$.